# Devise show user page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How would I create a page that allows the user to view their profile.

Anyone worked around/see/know an answer this problem? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not so much a devise problem as a simple routing issue:

Just create a `ProfileController` and an action `Show` and then do the following in your `routes.rb`:

```
match '/profile', :to => "profile#show"
```

Inside your profile#show action:

```
def show
  @profile = current_user
end
```

and in the view you display the information about the user that is stored in @profile.